# Using weights with transformers huggingface

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I came across this [tutorial](https://github.com/jlealtru/website_tutorials/blob/main/notebooks/Longformer%20with%20IMDB.ipynb) which performs Text classification with the Longformer. I came across this two links - [one](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-can-i-use-class-weights-when-training/1067) and [two](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/master/main_classes/trainer) which talk about using class weights when the data is unbalanced.

```
# instantiate the trainer class and check for available devices
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=test_data
)
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
device
```

I am not sure how to modify the above piece of code to include class weights as shown below (code copied from the last link from above)

```
from torch import nn
from transformers import Trainer


class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        labels = inputs.get("labels")
        # forward pass
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.get("logits")
        # compute custom loss (suppose one has 3 labels with different weights)
        loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]))
        loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.model.config.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

Could someone clarify how to combine above two blocks?

## update 1======================

as per the answer given below,
if I modify code , then do I need to provide more arguments when I create `trainer`   object so that `compute_loss` method gets used? would that method be called automatically? for example for that function one of the inputs is `inputs` and we are not feeding it when we create the `trainer` object

```
class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        labels = inputs.get("labels")
        # forward pass
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.get("logits")
        # compute custom loss (suppose one has 3 labels with different weights)
        loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]))
        loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.model.config.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss


# instantiate the trainer class and check for available devices
trainer = CustomTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset=test_data
)
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
device
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of instantiating a `Trainer` object, you can now simply have a `CustomTrainer`. This means, instead of writing

```py
trainer = Trainer(...)
```

you simply write

```py
trainer = CustomTrainer(...)
```

Since you inherit all the functions and default behavior from the `Trainer` class, the only difference will be the custom `compute_loss()` function.

Comment: could you reply update 1?

Comment: Please open a separate question for that. Updates are not supposed to add new questions. FWIW, as I've already addressed in my answer, all other functions (that are defined in the `Trainer` base class) remain functionally the same, so you do not need to change anything.

Comment: hi, i'm in the same situation as @user2543622 and have tried the code snippet they give in their update. The standard trainer (without customization) does work ok for me, but doesn't learn to predict both of my 2 labels, hence i want to try class weights. With the custom trainer, i see an error `RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper_nll_loss_forward)`. From searching around, I think I understand the problem, but am not sure how to resolve it in this code snippet

Comment: you need to make sure that you are putting everything on GPUs - try `to(device) ` command https://www.google.com/search?q=python+todevice&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS979US981&oq=python+todevice&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13i512j0i8i13i30l8.3975j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: thank you @user2543622, it turned out that the line `loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=torch.tensor([1.0,2.0,3.0]).to('cuda'))` in the compute_loss function is the one that needed amending (got the error that a datasets dictionary doesn't have a 'to' attribute, and the model was on cuda already). Noting it here in case anyone else visits this page